# import libusb "This OS is not supported yet!"

Tags: python, libusb, pyusb

I have been trying to code the display on my Ableton push 2 with python using this guide: github.com/ffont/push2-python#using-the-simulator, but I ran into a problem with pyusb and i was missing libusb. pip3 kept saying I already had it installed but I still kept getting errors when trying to use Libusb. So i tried using homebrew and it installed it but I still keep getting errors when using libusb.

this is what my terminal looks like when trying to import:

```
>>> import libusb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libusb/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ._libusb    import * ; del _libusb    # noqa
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libusb/_libusb.py", line 29, in <module>
    from ._platform import CFUNC
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libusb/_platform/__init__.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ._osx     import DLL_PATH, DLL, dlclose, CFUNC
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/site-packages/libusb/_platform/_osx/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    raise NotImplementedError("This OS is not supported yet!")
NotImplementedError: This OS is not supported yet!
```

Comment: You probably need to switch to another OS because the OS you are currently using is not yet supported by libusb.

Comment: How do I change the OS?

Comment: I don't know what OS you are currently using, but maybe this could be of help: https://ostoday.org/other/how-to-change-operating-system.html

Comment: ohhh. I am on mac would there be a way for me to fix this problem without changing my OS? I need libusb it appears to properly use pyusb

Comment: "Restart your Mac, and hold down the Option key until icons for each operating system appear onscreen. Highlight Windows or Macintosh HD, and click the arrow to launch the operating system of choice for this session." credit from https://www.dummies.com/computers/macs/how-to-switch-between-windows-and-os-x-with-macs-boot-camp/